# IntelliJ Community, remote debugging on server with user and password

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a java maven application. I want to remote debug this application on server. Im using IntellJ Community. I tried to connect to localhost jar by `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` and all works great. But now I want to debug application which is on remote server (I login into this server by Microsoft Remote Server by passing ip, user and password.) I run jar on server with argument from code snippet, but in intellij I get an error ("Connection timed out"). Is it any possibility to connect with host by user and password (in intellij debug configuration I only can set host and port)?

Comment: Have you created remote run configuration? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html

Comment: Yes. Everything seems good. I think the problem is that the server has password.